# Python min and max built-in module confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am supposed to write a function name shortest() that finds the length of the shortest string in a list of strings.

The function shortest() takes one parameter:
1. a list of strings, textList

The function shortest() should return the length of the shortest string in text List. You  may assume that textList contains at least one element (string).

For example, the following would be correct output:

```
>>> beatleLine = ['I', 'am', 'the', 'walrus']
>>> print(shortest(beatleLine))
1
```

--

When I finished writing the shortest() function, I came up with this solution

```
def shortest(textList):
    return len(max(textList))

string = ['Hey', 'Hello', 'Hi']
print(shortest(string))
```

But I am confused as to why the max function returns the length of the shortest function instead of the min function.

If I change max to min, the largest value is returned. It almost seems as if min and max are switched.

I am using Python 3.4 and running it on IDLE.

Answer (score 4):

`max` returns the largest item in an iterable. Since you didn't provide any `key` function to compare who is the `largest` it'll return the biggest element in lexicographical order:

```
>>> max(['I', 'am', 'the', 'x', 'walrus'])
'x'
```

You need to tell `max` to which key function it will use to compare elements for deciding who is the *largest*:

```
>>> max(['I', 'am', 'the', 'walrus', 'x'], key=len)
'walrus'
```

That being said:

```
>>> def shortest(textList):
...     return len(min(textList, key=len))
```

Alternatives using list comprehensions or `map`:

```
>>> min(len(text) for text in textList)
```

--

```
>>> min(map(len, textList))
```

Comment: Or even better `return min(len(text) for text in textList)`.

Comment: or `min(map(len, textList))`

Comment: You've made one mistake though. The default comparison is not "the last element in the list", it is "the biggest element in lexicographical order". That's why `x` is the biggest no matter where it is in the list.

Comment: BTW, why do you think passing min a generator is better than using `key` function? Code readability, performance?

Comment: `key` is only used for comparison while it does not modify objects. With list comprehension you actually convert objects, so the external `len(...)` is no longer required. It's a tiny thing but it is a bit more performant and more readable IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare the strings themselves as the function does (i.e. sort the list and display it), you'll see that they order them a specific way that gives the results you see.

You want to use the `key` argument to pass a function that will give the length of the item instead of using the item itself.